# Having Runtime error in C

Tags: c, algorithm

Me and my friend have written a code for C by catching algorithms from internet . Our program works well but in some cases we have run time error for our long code . Can you help me to make this code shorter ? 
This code catches names with uppercase and lower case letters and convert the first letters of words to uppercase and the others to lowercase . at first we should give the numbers of names that we want to put .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int ch, i,n,tool[100];
int main()
{
    int k, j , i;
    char sentence[100][100];
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(k=0;k<n+1;k++) {
        for (i = 0; (sentence[k][i] = getchar()) != '\n'; i++) {
            ;
        }
        sentence[k][i] = '\0';
        tool[k]=i;
        ch=toupper(sentence[k][0]);
        sentence[k][0]=ch;
        for (j = 1; j < i; j++) {
            if(sentence[k][j-1]==' ')
                ch=toupper(sentence[k][j]);
            else
                ch=tolower(sentence[k][j]);
                sentence[k][j]=ch; 
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n+1;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<tool[i];j++) {
            ch=sentence[i][j];
            putchar(ch);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are some inputs for which the program fails?

Comment: I don't know , because we must upload this code in a server and it test it and give us score , but it has some test cases that they have run time error and for this reason it reduce our score and don't say what are the test cases that have run time error . :(

Comment: Perhaps the input lines are longer than 100 characters? Or maybe there are more than 100 lines of input?

Comment: i don't think their code are more than 100 characters .

Comment: I must make this code shorter , but with same output.can you help ?

Comment: `for(k=0;k<n+1;k++)` are you sure? How many iterations are there?

Comment: Since you terminate each sentence with a null-character (`sentence[k][i] = '\0'`), you might as well `printf(sentence[i])` at the end of your program, using a single `for` loop (instead of that double `for` loop and `tool[i]`).

Answer (score 2):

Try this one..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
char *name,*backup_addr, **name_array;
int i,n,j;
main()
{
     char c;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    name_array=malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
            name_array[i]=malloc(sizeof(char));
            backup_addr=name=malloc(sizeof(char*));
            while(isspace(c=getchar()));
            if(isalpha(c))
            {
                    *name++=toupper(c);
                    for(j=0;(isalpha(c=getchar()))!='\n'&&c!='\n';j++,name++)
                                            *name=tolower(c);
            }
            *name='\0';
            name=backup_addr;
            name_array[i]=name;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            printf("%s\n",name_array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one that is measurably shorter. And in convenient function form as well:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/** convert string to sentence case.
*  returns string with initial cap and single i converted to uppercase.
*/
char *str2sentence (char *str)
{
    if (!str) return NULL;

    char *p = str;
    if ('a' <= *p && *p <= 'z')    /* convert first to upper */
        *p -= 32;
    p++;

    for ( ; *p; p++)    /* convert remaining to lower, except a single 'i' to upper 'I' */
    {
        if (*(p - 1) == 0x20 && *(p + 1) == 0x20)
        {
            if (*p == 'i')
                *p -= 32;
            else
                if ('A' <= *p && *p <= 'Z' && *p != 'I')
                    *p += 32;
        }
        else
            if ('A' <= *p && *p <= 'Z')
                *p += 32;
    }

    return str;
}

int main (void) {

    char *str = NULL;

    printf ("\n Enter a string to convert to sentence case ([enter] to quit)\n");

    while (printf ("\n  input : ") && scanf ("%m[^\n]%*c", &str) == 1)
        printf ("  result: %s\n", str2sentence (str));

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
./bin/str2sentence

 Enter a string to convert to sentence case ([enter] to quit)

  input : this IS A StrinG tO ConvERt.
  result: This is a string to convert.

  input : oR maYBe aNOTher OnE.
  result: Or maybe another one.

  input :
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
    char *array[100],*p;
    int i=0,j,n,k;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (n=n+1 ; n > 0 ; n--) { p=(char *)malloc(100);
            array[i++]=p;   
            for (k=0; (*p=getchar()) != '\n' && *p !=EOF ;p++, k++); *p='\0';       

            for ( p=p-k; *p !='\0'; p++) {  
                    if (isspace(*p) )
                            continue;
                    *p=toupper(*p); p++;
                    for( ; *p!=' ' && *p!='\0' ;p++ )
                            *p=tolower(*p);
                    if ( *p=='\0' ) p--;
            }
    }               

    for (j=0;  j<i ; j++)
            printf("%s\n",array[j]);
 }
```

Input is like your program.

Comment: thanks you so much for your help . but we can't use string.h in this code . can you change it again ?

Comment: You can use that without that header file it will work.

Comment: i have change it to ctype.h and it worked . thank you so much  Karthikeyan.R.S . I am Asian too . can we be friends ? here we can't have friendship . add me in facebook please . facebook.com/lordmh